# Return function(event, userData) both in callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Using a callback I'm getting the position of a child object and adding it to an array. I would also like to add a key to that id so I can search the array for it later. Then I can link the key of the originally created object, with a key in the position array.

I can't seem to get the callback for both to work. Is there a way you can pass `function(event, callback)` both back ?

Bonus points if you know why `this.props.onLayout` sends `e` in the callback, while this.props.onLayout() doesn't. I don't!

```
const dataArray = [{key: 0,id: 'A',},{key: 1,id: 'B',},{key: 2,id: 'Z',}]

// Root Component
export default class App extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <View>
            {this.getSomeText()}
            </
    getSomeText() {
        return dataArray.map( d =>
            <SomeText key={d.key} id={d.id} onLayout={(e) => this.onLayout(e)} />
        )
    }
    onLayout (e, id ) {
        // add these items to array
        // e.nativeEvent.Layout{Width,Height,x,y,id}
        // I can add the e data but the id data never comes through.
    }
}


// Child Component
class SomeText extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Text 
                onLayout={this.props.onLayout} 
                // onLayout as above this returns the event e but
                // 2. this.props.onLayout() // doesn't return e at all ??
                // 3. () => this.props.onLayout // doesn't work either, why?
                // 4. (e, this.props.key)  => this.props.onLayout(this.props.key)
                // 4 doesnt work either
                >Some text</Text>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<SomeText key={d.key} id={d.id} onLayout={(e) => this.onLayout(e, d.id)} />
```

However, you can also get the id from the event:

```
onLayout (e) {
  const id = e.target.id;
}
```

See some additions to your comments below:

```
<Text 
    onLayout={this.props.onLayout} 
    // onLayout as above this returns the event e but
    // 2. this.props.onLayout() // Calls the function during every render instead of assigning it.
    // 3. () => this.props.onLayout // Assigns the anonymous function, but when the event occurs and the anonymous function is called, you aren't calling your onLayout function.
    // 4. (e, this.props.key)  => this.props.onLayout(this.props.key)
    // this.props.key isn't being passed in by the event handler. Also, you are not passing the event to onLayout. Should be (e) => this.props.onLayout(e, this.props.key)
    >Some text</Text>
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer has helped me put the 'journey' of callbacks into perspective really appreciated.